# Access Google Calendar API with username/password

Tags: c#, .net, api

I am writing a small client to sync the outlook calendar on a machine with a user's google calendar. I am using .Net (C#).
I just read about accessing the Google Calendar API using the Google APIs Client Library for .NET and tried some basic stuff.

Now regarding the Authorization, as far as I understood, the new "OAuth 2.0" Authorization requires a "user consent", which means the user is directed to a google page where they must explicitly allow my application access to their calendar.
As if this user interaction is not enough, I as a programmer have to handle "access tokens" or "refresh tokens" and all that stuff.

Now my question is:
Is there really no easier way to have an installed application communicate with the google API to access a user's calendar?

I would like my user to enter his username/password in a "Settings" dialog. His credentials would be stored locally (encrypted of course) and then be used later on every access via google API. I know this can be dangerous and all that however I would like that decision to lie with me.

So, is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No that is not possible. The **entire point** of OAuth is the user never gives a 3rd party (you) their username and password. The only thing you get is a token that allows you to connect that the user can revoke at any time. (Also if the user changes his password, you can still use the same saved token and do not need to make the user update their settings).

If you decide to "work around" this by saving the username and pasword and performing the "authorization" yourself you will be in violation with the TOS of the API and will have your application banned by Google (or any OAuth provider if you try it with someone else) for not following the rules.

Comment: Thank you. No, I don't want to work around that. If that is how it is supposed to be done then so be it.
But how often will the user have to allow that access? Is it possible for this to only be done once?

Comment: Yes, you do it once, then you save the token it gives you on the disk, when you try to connect a second time, you try the old token first, and if you get a error code back (due to it being expired or revoked) then you prompt a second time to authorize. Most of the time you will only need to ask for authorization once.

Comment: thank you! Is there any example somewhere of how to do this in C# (get the token after user has given their consent). I only found examples of how to establish the connection itself.

Comment: Also, is there a more elegant way than having a browser window pop up where the user logs in and then has to copy/paste (!) a code to my application?

Comment: For the example code, no I don't have any. But you can display the authorization page in a WebBrowser control. After they authorize you can have Google return the key in the URL or the header of web page so the user does not need to copy anything.

Comment: How does Mac OSX calendar application get around this? It asks for username/password?

Comment: @PeterT Most likely it is not using the public API, Apple and Google worked out a contract to provide a private API that does not use OAuth.

Comment: see also my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55981592/using-the-google-calendar-app-password-in-ruby, I have an example there that uses a logon without token into gmail and am looking for a calendar solution